# Erlang gen_server process does not exit when it does not trap exit

Tags: linux, erlang, gen-server

buddies,
i have a question about Erlang gen_server.
Code episode is here:
file: akita_cluster_info.erl

> ```
> start_link() ->
>     gen_server:start_link({global, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).
>
> init([]) ->
>     c:nl(akita_collector_local),
>     rpc:multicall(akita_collector_local, start, []),
>     {ok, #state{}}.
> ```

file: akita_collector_local.erl

> ```
> start() ->
>     gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []). 
>
> init([]) ->
>     %%process_flag(trap_exit, true),
>     init_dets_file(),
>     io:format("dic: ~w~n", [get()]),
>     {ok, #state{}}.
> ```

The output from the shell is like:
do not trap exit:

> Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
>   (akita@hao)1> akita_cluster_info:start_link().
>   dic: [{'$ancestors',[<0.50.0>]},{'$initial_call',{akita_collector_local,init,1}}]
>   receive info: {init_dets,{akita@hao,ok}}
>   {ok,<0.48.0>}
>   (akita@hao)2>

trap exit:

> Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
>   (akita@hao)1> akita_cluster_info:start_link().
>   dic: [{'$ancestors',[<0.50.0>]},{'$initial_call',{akita_collector_local,init,1}}]
>   terminated with Reason: normal
>   receive info: {init_dets,{akita@hao,ok}}
>   receive info: {collector_close,{akita@hao,normal}}
>   {ok,<0.48.0>}
>   (akita@hao)2>

When `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` is **not commented**, the **akita_collector_local** gen_server process will exit immediately because its parent process (that generated in rpc:multicall) dies. I know this is normal.
What is weird is that when there is no `process_flag(trap_exit, true)`, the **akita_collector_local** gen_server process **can survive**!!  Since it can not trap exit, it should have exitted right away. (this theory is right and i tested in Erlang shell). But why the gen_server process does not exit in this case. I have no idea.
Can you help me? Thank you very much.
Brs,
Ruan

ps: i figure the tricky part maybe lie in **rpc:multicall**

Comment: Could you post details on the test you did on the shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because the process generated in rpc:multicall exited with the reason ***normal***.

When two processes are linked, if one of them exits with the reason ***normal***, the other one without trap_exit won't exist.

And when `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` is **not commented**, in the source code of gen_server.erl, we can see this:

```
346 decode_msg(Msg, Parent, Name, State, Mod, Time, Debug, Hib) ->
347     case Msg of
348         {system, From, Req} ->
349             sys:handle_system_msg(Req, From, Parent, ?MODULE, Debug,
350                 [Name, State, Mod, Time], Hib);
351         {'EXIT', Parent, Reason} ->
352                 terminate(Reason, Name, Msg, Mod, State, Debug);
```

Gen_server will **terminate automatically** as long as its parent (The process which generates the gen_server) exits.